# jquery delay toggle searchbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, delay

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to get my searchbar to toggle when hovering over a button. I want it to toggle with a delay. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $("#search-form").hover(
      function(){
          $("#search-input").delay(700).toggleClass("collapse");
      }
  )
});
```

And here the HTML:

```
<form id="search-form" style="display:flex-end;" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse">
          </button>
          <input id="search-input" class="collapse form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        </form>
```

So the toggle works, but it seems to just ignore the delay. Where did I go wrong? Not sure if relevant, but I'm using bootstrap 4.5.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery API documentation:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases. (https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

It is not perfectly documented (as far as I can tell), but `toggleClass()` is not a function that uses the built-in effects queue.

Easiest solution is to use the vanilla `window.setTimeout()` function:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    $("#search-form").hover(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          $("#search-input").toggleClass("collapse");
      }, 700)
    });
});
```

PS: The above solution, while it will technically work, it will not behave how you'd expect to, when you're moving fast on/off the form with the mouse pointer. See the simulation below:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    $("#search-form").hover(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          $("#search-input").toggleClass("collapse");
      }, 700)
    });
});
```

```css
/* Border - just to highlight the form */
#search-form {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form" style="display:flex-end;" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse">BUTTON
          </button>
          <input id="search-input" class="collapse form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        </form>
```

Instead, you might want to opt for a CSS-only solution which avoids the above misbehavior automatically (using the `transition` CSS property and its `delay` option):

```js
// No JavaScript needed :)
```

```css
/* Border - just to highlight the form */
#search-form {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#search-form #search-input {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.7s;
}
#search-form:hover #search-input {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="search-form" style="display:flex-end;" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse">BUTTON
          </button>
          <input id="search-input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search"><!-- NOTE: no `collapse` class here anymore -->
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delay only works with the jQuery effects queues, so it's perfect for slides and fades like this.
So there are another ways to add delay:

Use setTimeout Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $("#search-form").hover(
        function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#search-input").toggleClass("collapse");
            }, 700);
    });
});
```

or

you can use jQueryUI

```
$("#search-input").toggleClass("collapse",800);
```

see [Toggle Class with delay](https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)